# IDA decompiled function signature mismatch

Tags: ida

I am on the last version of IDA.

There is a function B, that its signature is `B(int a,int b)`.

There is a function A that calls it. 
But in function A, the call appears like `B(12)` for example.

How do I make it synchronized / decompile just function A again?

Thanks.

Comment: it might be beneficial if you would show us some assembly esp. around the call B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to function A and press `y` on the call to B, and edit to `int B(int a, int b)`

Comment: yeh, right. so simple.